# Function does not push item from the same row in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this problem where the data in the same column is not push. Like it gets the first column right, but i resets back to 0 then get the first element in the second column, and same goes for the other columns.

Sample data would be: 
hubs = [Manila,QC] 
new_values = [[Manila, J, U], [QC, P, B], [Pasay, L, M]]

Details should return: details = [[Manila, J, U], [QC, P, B]]

But right now, the output is:

[[Pasay,J,U],[QC,P,B]]

```
function getEmails() {
  var id = "1043Hz7L2txTWNPN4wO5l3f6KpPPmgwmLgUyqhHwNeYs"
  var officer_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("officer")
  var new_values = officer_sheet.getRange(1,1,officer_sheet.getLastRow(), officer_sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var hubs = GetHubsToSend();

  var details = [];
  for (var i = 0, j = 0; i< new_values.length, j< hubs.length ;i++, j++){
       if(new_values[i][0] = hubs[j])          
       {
       details.push(new_values[i]);
       }
      }
  Logger.log(details);
  return details;
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested for loop - currently your loop checks `new_array[n][0] to hubs[n]` - because `i` always == `j`

Also, to check for equality, use `==` or `===` ... because `=` is an assignment operator, and in this case will always also be truthy for the if condition

The code below does what you expect

```js
var hubs = ['Pasay', 'QC'];
var new_values = [['Manila', 'J', 'U'], ['QC', 'P', 'B'], ['Pasay', 'L', 'M']]
var details = [];
for (var j = 0; j < hubs.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < new_values.length; i++) {
        if (new_values[i][0] == hubs[j]) {
            details.push(new_values[i]);
        }
    }
}
console.log(details);
```